# How do I read the windows registry (Default) value using QSettings?

Tags: c++, qt, registry, powerpoint

I want to read the registry to find the current PowerPoint version.

However this just returns Zero:

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\PowerPoint.Application\\CurrVer",
                   QSettings::NativeFormat);

QString sReturnedValue = settings.value("(Default)", "0").toString();
```

Any suggestions as to how I get the value from a (default) key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, just figured it out. Whilst `regedit` shows it as (Default) you just read it as Default.

```
QString sReturnedValue = settings.value( "Default", "0" ).toString();
```

Comment: For most things, "" means the default key, I don't see how "Default" could work, what happens when there is a real value named Default in the same key?

Comment: Qt has assert in QSettings on key.isEmpty()

Comment: The [docs for QSettings.value](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html#value) says **providing a second argument returns the second argument as a default value if it can't find the key.** That's not at all what the question was asking for.

Comment: @CarlWalsh I know what question I asked and what I answered. Changing from (Default) to Default got me the version number I was looking for. Why are you focused on what I passed in as the second argument?

Comment: My mistake, I thought that the difference in your answer was the addition of a second argument, but I see that is wrong. I also missed that you asked the question. Two mistakes!

Answer (score 4):

Also, a period works:

```
RegReader.value(".", NULL).toString();
```